# How can I get an element's position in a list?

Tags: c++, list, position, element

Let's say I have a list :

`std::list<std::string> myList ("hi", "hello", "hey");`

How can I get `"hello"`'s position in `myList`?

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I've changed to a std::vector now.

Comment: `std::distance(myList.begin(), std::find(myList.begin(), myList.end(), "hello"))` Note though that `std::list` is perhaps the worst possible choice of a container if you need to work in terms of positions.

Comment: You can try `vector` and `deque`.

Comment: yes, use a vector instead